# Ajax tutorial for post and get

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need a simple ajax tutorial or case study for a simple input form, where I want to post a username through an input form, which sends it to the database and replies with the results.
Any recommendation for such tutorial is welcome, because I've only got one using Mootool but I'm searching for one using jQuery!

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#results").append(html);
  }
});
```

This code will append the content of `test.html` file to `#results` element

You can find more information at [jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

**Update:**

Use this code to send POST data and output result.

```
var menuId = $("ul.nav").first().attr("id");
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {id : menuId},
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  $("#log").html( msg );
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Answer (score 43):

Assuming you have some html like:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
<div id="resultarea"></div>
```

You would use a `<script>` like:

```
var myusername = $("#username").val();
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "serverscript.xxx",
  data: myusername,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
     $("#resultarea").text(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: You may need to set the parameter name, like data : "username=" + myusername

Comment: you can also do ajax for somes case with this library https://github.com/Guseyn/EHTML, using only HTML

Comment: You can use above for post also and also can add dataType like json eg :- dataType: 'json',

Comment: Note that you must pass data parameters either in json, object or array, like this https://codetopology.com/scripts/jquery/jquery-ajax-method-with-example/#Example_2_-_Ajax_POST_Request