# Cross domain ajax request untrusted certificate (jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

How to avoid certificate check using jquery?

```
 $.getJSON("https://loopback-api:3000/api/SMS-APIs/getBalance?callback=?", function(result){
     console.log(result);
  });
```

Getting following error:

> net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Any ideas?

Comment: in short, you can't. longer explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723415/bypassing-ssl-certificate-error-in-jquery-and-ajax by @Alex K.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if ajax call failed due to insecure response or connection refused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058764/determine-if-ajax-call-failed-due-to-insecure-response-or-connection-refused)