# I get a problem with ajax get request can someone help me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

My code do not response any data to me..
bellow some code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function matriculaFn(mat) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url:'My url API,
        async: true,
        crossDomain: false,
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Token xxxprivatexxxxx"
        },
        options: {
            useSSL: true
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var dados = JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log(dados);
            $("#IDDOCAMPO").val(data.AlgumaCoisa);
        },
        //error : function(xhr, status, error) {
        // do stuff here
        //var data = jQuery.getJSON(xhr.responseText);
        //console.log(data); 
        //}
    });
  };
</script>
```

here is the error:

> jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 OPTIONS https://url net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

Comment: can you show us the url?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bypassing SSL certificate error in jQuery and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723415/bypassing-ssl-certificate-error-in-jquery-and-ajax)

Comment: I try it, but in my case i have a token...

Comment: what's this attribute ? `url: 'https:url...` ?? `url` is not defined and it's not a valid syntac

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet because I don't have enough rep but it looks as though this error is Chrome specific. Have you tried other browsers? If so, try some of the methods listed here: [link](https://comodosslstore.com/resources/how-to-fix-net-err_cert_date_invalid-error-on-google-chrome/)

Other things you could try are:

```
crossDomain: true,
```

or adding:

```
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
},
```

or because it's a GET request try:

```
dataType: 'jsonp',
```

Comment: i got it trying your answer net::ERR_ABORTED 401