# Reading in XML or JSON from file on local server

Tags: javascript, json, xml, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to load a list of coordinates for use in a google map from either an XML file or a JSON file (I have both hosted in same directory on local test server). I have used a hard-coded JSON object to load map coordinates to test so far. My question is, how do I replace that fake/hard-coded JSON with the XML/JSON file on my server?  Here's my code:

```
  (function() {

  // Creating an array that will contain all of our product icons
  var productIcons = [];

  productIcons['bulletin'] = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'icons/Bulletin-sm.png', 
    new google.maps.Size(48, 48), 
    null, 
    new google.maps.Point(24, 24)
  );

  productIcons['bus'] = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'icons/busicon.png', 
    new google.maps.Size(48, 48), 
    null, 
    new google.maps.Point(24, 24)
  );

  productIcons['bench'] = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'icons/BusBench-sm.png', 
    new google.maps.Size(48, 48), 
    null, 
    new google.maps.Point(24, 24)
  );

  productIcons['junior'] = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'icons/JuniorPoster-sm.png', 
    new google.maps.Size(48, 48), 
    null, 
    new google.maps.Point(24, 24)
  );

  productIcons['poster'] = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'icons/Poster-sm.png', 
    new google.maps.Size(48, 48), 
    null, 
    new google.maps.Point(24, 24)
  );


  productIcons['shelter'] = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'icons/TransitShelter-sm.png', 
    new google.maps.Size(48, 48), 
    null, 
    new google.maps.Point(24, 24)
  );

  window.onload = function() {

    // Creating a map
    var options = {  
      zoom: 3,  
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09, -95.71),  
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
    };  
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);  


// Creating a JSON object with fake product data (to be replaced by XML or JSON)
var productData = {'product': [
{
'lat': 40.756054,
'lng': -119.986951,
'productType': 'junior'
},
{
'lat': 35.620973,
'lng': -121.347276,
'productType': 'shelter'
},
{
'lat': 40.620973,
'lng': -121.347276,
'productType': 'bus'
},
{
'lat': 39.120973,
'lng': -122.847276,
'productType': 'bench'
},
{
'lat': 35.920973,
'lng': -122.347276,
'productType': 'bulletin'
},
{
'lat': 37.775206,
'lng': -122.419209,
'productType': 'poster'
}
]};
// Looping through the product array in productData
for (var i = 0; i < productData.product.length; i++) {
// creating a variable that will hold the current product object
var product = productData.product[i];
// Creating marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(product.lat, product.lng),
map: map,
icon: productIcons[product.productType]
});

}
}
})();
```

Comment: You'll have to load the JSON file using server-side code, since the browser does not have access to your server-side files.  You could potentially inject the JSON into your page for use by the Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking you could possibly setup a RESTFUL web service on your server and then use jquery's ajax capability to fetch the JSON content off from it.

A ajax tutorial:
[Ajax tutorial for post and get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get)

As for the RESTFUL web service side, there are many technologies which you can explore. Just search for "java restful web service tutorial" or ".NET WCF RESTFUL"

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your help- that's just what I needed.