# ajax form display message

Tags: ajax, dbase

i have a form that insert in dbase what i write
here is the form,

```
        <form  id="contact-form" class="bl_form text-center" action="<?php echo "index.php?page=rooms&room=$rid&amp;rpw=$rpw&amp;r=$r"; 

?>" method="post" novalidate>
                    <span class="field-wrap scrollimation fade-right">

                        <input type="hidden" id="contact-name" name="contactName" type="text" 

class="label_better requiredField" data-new-placeholder="Name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo "$uid"; ?>" data-error-

empty="*Enter your name">
                    </span>
                                        <span class="field-wrap scrollimation fade-left">
                        <label class="control-label" for="contact-message">Message</label>
                        <textarea id="contact-message" name="message" rows="1" class="label_better 

requiredField" data-new-placeholder="Message" placeholder="Message" data-error-empty="*Enter your message"></textarea>
                    </span>

                    <p class="text-center"><button  name="sy2" id="submit_post" type="submit" class="btn btn-meflat 

icon-left" data-error-message="Error!" data-sending-message="Sending..." data-ok-message="Message Sent"><i class="fa fa-paper-

plane"></i>Send Message</button></p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                    <?php echo "<postfield name=\"message\" value=\"$(message)\"/>"; ?>
                </form>
```

and i want to put a ajax code that display this message from dbase

```
<?php echo make_clickable($tosay)."$link_delete"; ?>
```

Can someone provide me an example?Thank you

Comment: and i want to display message instantly like chat,if a user wants to write in the form automatically display if i can see the message

Answer (score 0):

> Look at this
>   [Ajax tutorial for post and get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get)

So, the jQuery

```
$('body').on('submit', '#contact-form', function(){
  $.post({$(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data){
    if(data){
      alert(data.message);
    }
  }, 'json');
  return false;
});
```

And the server side

```
<?php 
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    // do your thing here
    echo json_encode(array("message" => make_clickable($tosay).$link_delete));
    die();
  }
?>
```

Comment: and if is in the same page? the link is like in the form where i post

Comment: Did you test what I gave to you?

Comment: is not working....is not showing the message and also dosent show the row inserted instantly like in a chat

Comment: i will give you all the file as txt file