# executing php code within javascript on button click

Tags: javascript, php, html

Am trying to execute php code within javascript with button onclick event.
I have two pages *test.php* and *demo.php* with button in each page. Now what I want to do is. when I click button in *test.php*, it should disable the button in *demo.php* and when *test.php* is reloaded,it should check the status of button in *demo.php* and according to that it should display it.

Now I have tried something which works fine as per the requirement. problem is that button on both pages doesn't work. code executes only when the page is refreshed.

Here is the code that I have tried.

first ***test.php***

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function enable(){
var a='<?php

$_SESSION['demo']='enable';
if($_SESSION['btn_demo']=='enabled'){

$_SESSION['btn_test']='disable';
unset($_SESSION['demo']);
}
else {
    $_SESSION['btn_test']='enable';
}
?>';

}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['btn_test']; ?>" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="enable()" >

</body>
</html>
```

when I click on enable button in *test.php* , it should enable the button in *demo.php*.

second ***demo.php***

```
<?php 
session_start();
error_reporting(0);


?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function enable(){
    <?php 
$_SESSION['test']=$_SESSION['demo'];
if($_SESSION['test']=='enable'){
$_SESSION['btn_demo']='enabled';    
} else
{
    $_SESSION['btn_demo']='disabled';
}   

?>}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<style>

</style>

<input type="button" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['btn_demo']; ?>" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="enable()" >

 </body>
  </html>
```

here the button should be enabled/disabled when button in *test.php* is clicked.
this both pages work fine when I refresh. doesn't work when either of the button is clicked. how to solve this ? need help.

Comment: You have to use AJAX, you can't execute PHP directly from JS function.

Comment: how do I do that..? any suggestions.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get) is example.

Comment: can I ask why this is downvoted.?

Comment: It wasn't me, but I think that it's because there is so many similar questions in SO.

Answer (score 1):

PHP executes before the javascript, so you cannot use in this way, You can call the file using AJAX

Try something like this:

```
<script>
    function enable(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "setSession.php",
            success: function(res) {
                if(res==="Success"){
                    alert("Success!!!");
                }
            }
        });      
    }
</script>
```

setSession.php

```
<?php
$_SESSION['demo']='enable';
if($_SESSION['btn_demo']=='enabled'){
    $_SESSION['btn_test']='disable';
    unset($_SESSION['demo']);
}
else {
    $_SESSION['btn_test']='enable';
}
echo "Success";
?>
```

Comment: whether Ajax will redirect the page? if so, then I can't coz I don't want to redirect the page. only pass the value when  button is clicked

Comment: AJAX will not redirect the page, but it does exactly what you want

Comment: It executes your code behind and sends the result to your current page without refreshing your entire page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93777/discussion-between-sagar-pawar-and-vijaya-sankar-n).