# Form submission to alternative URL

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress within a page template I have a custom registration form which upon submit redirects to:

```
<form name="registerform" id="registerform" action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post' ) ); ?>" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Of course `wp-login.php` is where all the magic happens. Thing is I really want my errors displayed right on the page where the error happens. I don't want to be re-directed to `wp-login.php?action=register` .

How can I stay on page and display the errors inline?

Comment: Take a look at AJAX methods - [AJAX Post Tutorial](https://www.airpair.com/js/jquery-ajax-post-tutorial), [jQuery AJAX get() and post() methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp), [Ajax tutorial for post and get (StackOverflow)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get)

Comment: Are you aware of a Wordpress hook that I can use from within the API?