# Data not rendered by $.ajax, data being present in view-source

Tags: jquery, ajax, url

I am making a get request by using

```
$.ajax{type:'GET', url: url, cache: false..}
```

Although i am able to view the data by view-source. But unable to see on the page, it shows empty. What can be the reason for behavior and how can it be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this link will assist you

[Ajax tutorial for post and get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get)

The main thing is that you need to select a target element, and then output on success.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `url` you are providing contains the `GET` parameters.