# Change HTML Object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to develop a site that on entering a value into an input changes page content. I have gotten this to work with my photos. I am pulling text from a .txt file using HTML "Object".

I want to change the file path for the text file using the input as the parent folder. 
I tried using inner.html, and setting the id data =  but neither worked.

I'm open to any suggestions.

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("stud").value ;
  var a = x + "/img1.jpg" ;
  var b = x + "/img2.jpg" ;
  var text_hold = x + "/text/text.txt" ;
  img1.src= a ;
  img2.src= b ;
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "data='jeff/stock/text/text.txt'" ;
}
```

Comment: forgot the element
 <div><object id="content" data="stock/text/text.txt"></object></div>

Comment: Don't put corrections into the comments, edit the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax tutorial for post and get](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is an attribute, it's not the HTML contents of the object. Use `setAttribute` to set it.

```
document.getElementById('content').setAttribute('data', 'jeff/stock/text/text.txt');
```