# Post to another page without redirecting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am building a movie recommended system. I want when a user login and rate a movie, the rating and movie name as well as user name will post to another page without going to that page automatically, i mean without pressing anything. How can I do that?

Comment: DId you even Google your title/question first?

Comment: In any case; the question is way too broad and showed no effort.

Comment: So... what have you tried?

Comment: Yes, i searched a lot..but i want to post title, username and rating automatically when user rate a movie.

Comment: well, someone provided you with an answer below, see that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by executing an [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get) request (after clicking the vote-button), which sends data (you can define the data to be what you want - rating, movie and user) to a php script that you will have to create.

the php script will read the posted data that the ajax has sent and can insert/update the database.

This way, the user will not be redirected. he won't even notice.

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this by using some kind of ajax requests triggered by `vote` event or callback.

Comment: that's a pretty vague answer, wouldn't you agree if someone gave you the same type of answer? think about it for a minute.

Comment: That downvote you just received, I can honestly say is not mine.