# Using AJAX post instead of form but condition on $_POST is never met

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, post

I'm currently trying to send data to the same page using the selected value in a table row. The user selection gets highlighted and then when the button's onsubmit event is fired, the script is run.

I'm trying to retrieve the `$_POST` data on the same page, in order for the user to see a new form that they need to fill out and not showing the previous table anymore, but I never get to the inside of an `if` statement that checks if it isset lik this:

```
isset($_POST['xx'])
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here. This is my code so far:

```
$(".mypost").on("click",function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "../ajout-correctifs/",
        type: "POST",
        data: { selectedcoll: $("#MyTable1 tr.selected input").val()},
        success: function(response){    
            window.location = "../ajout-correctifs/";
            //alert(response);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("POST METHOD ERROR : DATA NOT POSTED - IMMINENT PAGE RELOAD..");
            window.location = "../ajout-correctifs/";
        }
    });
});
```

Additional Information:

- the `$("#MyTable1 tr.selected input")` is what helps me retrieve whatever the user has selected.
- the `alert("response")` displays html code

**EDIT : Here is my php file :**

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SofiaEO/mypage/master/mycode.php

**EDIT : SOLUTION** in case someone else has the same issue

I deleted the `url` value + I used `$('body').html(response)` to print the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check ajax "url" param.
2. In your success function you have used "window.location".
   You can not do this because after the redirect you lose the "data" of ajax post and is always false the condition in the "new" redirected page: "isset($_POST['xx'])".

So for avoid this NOT REDIRECT after an ajax response. Remove window.location in your success function;

Visit this: [Ajax tutorial for post and get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get)

Comment: I just tried out the solution you posted; got rid of the redirection  and all but the thing is when I inject the success function's response onto the div element it just prints out html as plain text; what I want to retrieve is specifically the $_POST value not to be injected in an HTML element but to be used as a variable.

Comment: Plus, the other part of the page that loads when $_POST is set doesn't show, instead I have my table in which I select a value to be posted and the plain HTML code right after..

Comment: For showing the html code below the "isset"  use jquery in your success function. Find that code (ex: $(response).find('#mytable');) and after append the finded code where you want in your current html page.

Comment: Probabily becouse in your data ajax, you submit only one parameter. You post in ajax only "selectedcoll" param, other params is empty.

Comment: Thank you for your help; the comments, tips and link all helped me.