# How do I get a list of users from the Json API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I want to download the AJAX user list available at http://zadanie.ee/users.json, And I would like to display

1.The number of all users, 
2.The Number of active users, 
3.The Number of active women, 
4.The Number of active men,

from JSON API, using jquery/javascript etc,

How can I achieve this? or can some one provide me a simple tutorial to start with?

Here is what I have done so far :

CODE:

```
<script>

function ViewData()
{

  $.getJSON("http://zadanie.ee/users.json",
   function(data)
   {
     var items = [];

     $.each(data.Users,
      function(key, value)
      {
        items.push("<li>" +
         value.username + "<br />" +
         value.active + "<br />" +

         + "</li>");
      });
     $('<ul/>', {html: items.join(")}).
      appendTo('body');
   });
}
</script>
```

Any help or any idea will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: How come the gender is a list? There are some people that have male and female as gender. So are they considered as men, female or both?

Comment: @SamuelToh I guess it could be both to recognize a transgender

Comment: This question have nothing to do with AngularJS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax tutorial for post and get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
         $.getJSON("http://zadanie.laboratorium.ee/users.json",function(data)
        {
             var items = [];
             var number_of_user = 0;
             var number_of_active_user = 0;
             var number_of_active_men = 0;
             var number_of_active_women = 0;
                 $.each(data,
                  function(key, value)
                  {
                    number_of_user += 1;
                    if(value['active'] == true){
                        if(value['gender'][0] == 'Female' || value['gender'][0] == 'female'){
                            number_of_active_women +=1;
                        }
                        else if(value['gender'][0] == 'Male' || value['gender'][0] == 'male'){
                            number_of_active_men +=1;
                        }
                    }

                  });
                console.log("number_of_user ==> "+number_of_user +" number_of_active_user ==> "+ number_of_active_user +" number_of_active_men ==> "+ number_of_active_men +" number_of_active_women ==> "+ number_of_active_women);
       });
     });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hii bro can you put it in jsfiddle?

Comment: This link is not working well in jsfiddle because in fiddle we need to use https instead of the http.And i did only jQuery/javascript code nothing else.

Comment: I had some problems on my computer now it works, how to put those output in HTML (the best way)?

Comment: You just need to this thing in <body> part <div class="div-output"></div> and in jQuery you just need to use (".div-output").html("number_of_user ==> "+number_of_user +" number_of_active_user ==> "+ number_of_active_user +" number_of_active_men ==> "+ number_of_active_men +" number_of_active_women ==> "+ number_of_active_women). So it will set all the console.log data in div and one more thing is html() will clear your previous result. So instead of the html() you also used append() both will work. Append add data without clearing old one.

Comment: hii, I tried your method I get error  "div.output".html is not a function,

Comment: solved the issue thank you for your support though I was missing $ :(

Comment: if I want to display the number of users who logged in over the last 6 months, what function should I use?

Comment: For that you need to use javascript date object.Here you just need to increment is_active_user if date is <= 6 months.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150133/discussion-between-jefferson-x-masonic-and-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd).

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX to read data and then parse it accordingly.

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: '"http://zadanie.laboratorium.ee/users.json"', 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { 
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            console.log(element.username);
        });
    }
});
```