# Extract from JS to url

Tags: javascript, php, forms

But I would be interested in how I can send this result from the js as a get

```
<form method="GET" action="order2.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="obj" price="5" value="1" >5
<input type="checkbox" name="obj" price="15" value="2">15
<input type="checkbox" name="obj" price="20" value="3">20
<input type="submit" value="send">
<div id="test"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(":input").change(function() {
var values = $('input:checked').map(function () {
return $(this).attr('price');;
}).get();
var total = 0;
$.each(values,function() {
total += parseFloat(this);
});
$("#test").text(total);
});
</script>
</form>
```

When I select inputs 1 and 2 so that the result is in url order2.php?price=20

Answer (score 0):

When a form submits, it will append all of it's inputs to the query string or post data (depending on the request type). A very simple way to add another field parameter called `price` with the sum is just to add a hidden input and update that dynamically with the sum.

Notice that I remove the `name` attribute from the checkboxes. I did this so that they wouldn't be send on the form submission.

I also replaced your `forEach` with a [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as it is more functional and you can chain it with the [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
$("#myform input").change(function() {
    var total = $('input:checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).attr('price');
    }).get().reduce(function(sum, value) {
        return sum + parseFloat(value);
    }, 0);
    $(".price").val(total);
    $(".price").html(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" method="GET" action="order2.php">
    <input type="checkbox" price="5" value="1" >5
    <input type="checkbox" price="15" value="2">15
    <input type="checkbox" price="20" value="3">20
    <input type="hidden" name="price" class="price"/>
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
<span class="price"></span>
```

Comment: Ok, but now I can not see the price for the snooping

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(":input").change(function() {
  var values = $('input:checked').map(function () {
    return $(this).attr('price');;
  }).get();
  
  var total = 0;
  $.each(values,function() {
    total += parseFloat(this);
  });
  
 
  $("#test").text(total);

  $('form').attr('action', 'order2.php?price=' + total);
  console.log ( $('form').attr('action') ) ;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
But I would be interested in how I can send this result from the js as a get
When I select inputs 1 and 2 so that the result is in url order2.php?price=20

<form method="GET" action="order2.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="obj" price="5" value="1" >5
  <input type="checkbox" name="obj" price="15" value="2">15
  <input type="checkbox" name="obj" price="20" value="3">20
  <input type="submit" value="send">
  <div id="test"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Surely rebuilding the action is more effort than using the default action of form parameters with a GET request?

Comment: The result is still order2.php?obj=1&obj=2

Answer (score 0):

From your description that when you select option 1 and 2, you have the sum of the options as the price. I'll break this down into steps:

1. You have to sum the selected options
2. Construct your query param
3. Use Ajax to make your get request

This guides through how to do [Ajax tutorial for post and get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get).
Hope this helps...

Comment: I don't think OP wants to send the request asynchronously.