# How to show HTML received after POST?

Tags: javascript, html, http, post

Maybe that's easy, but I cannot find any solution. I have an endpoint, which accepts POST requests with specific values and returns HTML. How should I properly do this request to show received HTML in browser?

In simple english, I'd like to have something like `<a>` tag, but with specified http method, headers etc. used during clicking on it.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please be more specific and include working examples or demonstrations of what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms

Comment: the usual way, what have you tried?

Comment: Using ajax? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it.

```
fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then((html) => {
        // change the content of an element to the html received
        el.innerHTML = html

        // append the html to the body
        document.body.innerHTML += html;
    })
```