# Every other ajax call has a 300ms delay

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I noticed a really weird behavior with my ajax calls.  Every other ajax call always have a 300ms delay.

Here is what the network section [look like](https://i.gyazo.com/1bc63205bcd2873f468b0af5d654212b.png).  I looked at the details of the call.  Here is the [fast ajax call](https://i.gyazo.com/fb59b79d304b8139537719cb4bfd379c.png), and here is the [slow ajax call](https://i.gyazo.com/b7d2ae37a00f43cc987c0249a288e4ef.png).

The slow ajax call has 2 extra fields - DNS lookup and Initial Connection.

Why does this happen every other ajax call?  How can I ensure consistent ajax performance?

**The test code:**

```
<body>
    <input type="button" class="btn" id="testButton" value="Test"/>
</body>

<script>
    document.getElementById('testButton').onclick = function() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                console.log('done');
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "{% url 'test_ajax' %}", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

---

```
def test_ajax(request):
    return JsonResponse({'a': 'a'})
```

EDIT:  I tried doing the ajax call with jQuery, still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I do not conceive performing an AJAX request without jQuery. Maybe the following question can enlight you:

[Ajax tutorial for post and get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get)

Your view function is in the right path.

Comment: I tried using jQuery to make the ajax call, and the result is the same.  300ms delay on every other call.