# "wrong-password" feedback directly inside form

Tags: javascript, php

I'm relatively new to PHP and I'm creating a login form. The connection with my db and the password verification is working fine, but I can't find a solution for getting a "wrong password" feedback directly in my form like shown in the picture at the end.

My form requires just a password the user will get from me. The form code looks like that:

```
<form name="download" id="download" method="post" action="download.php">
         <label for="password">Passwort</label><br>
         <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required> <br>
         <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Download">
</form>
```

and my download.php like this:

```
$pw = ($_POST['password']);
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT passwort FROM downloads WHERE id= :id");
$result = $statement->execute(array(':id' => 4));
$stored = $statement->fetch();
if(password_verify($pw, $stored['passwort'])){
    header("Location: test.pdf");
}
else{
    echo "Wrong password";
}
```

Instead of the `else{ echo "wrong password";}`, which is written on a blank new page, I would like to get some feedback like in the picture below.

[image: Stackoverflow Login Form]

Comment: That'll be an Ajax request then...

Comment: You need to know [What is Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get)

Comment: Why do you ``echo $stored['passwort'];`` ? This sent the stored password back to the browser...?

Comment: acctualy you could stay working like that... but, you sould put that echo inside the HTML element thats show the message, but as the comments above said, ajax would be more user friendly

Comment: Okay, thank you very much.

Comment: @ino password_verify verifies, that passwords that were hashed using the password_hash function are equal to some input.