# I need to receive fetch post from my wordpress to phonegap using wordpress rest api & json

Tags: wordpress, phonegap, wordpress-rest-api

please i need help concerning phonegap and wordpress rest api.. I am a bit new to phonegap. i want to be able to receive my latest posts using GET etc and likely post from my mobile and also possibly perform other CRUD operation. thanks

Comment: use ajax call..

Comment: can you show me how? thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9436702/7189547

Comment: thanks much i appreciate your effort. t really helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it done already thanks much. I am posting my code here to help some out there and these community:

// Device Event Listener

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
var portfolioPostsContainer = document.getElementById("portfolio-posts-container");
var portfolioPostsContainer2 = document.getElementById("portfolio-posts-container2");


function onDeviceReady(){

 var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://mydomain/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed');
 ourRequest.onload = function() {
  if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status < 400) {
    var data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    createHTML(data);
    console.log(data);

  // portfolioPostsBtn.remove();
} else {
  console.log("We connected to the server, but it returned an error.");
}
};

ourRequest.onerror = function() {
  console.log("Connection error");
};

ourRequest.send();

}


function createHTML(postsData) {
 var ourHTMLString = '';
 var postid ='';


for (i = 0; i < postsData.length; i++) {

 var posturl = postsData[i].link;
 ourHTMLString +='<tr>';

 ourHTMLString += '<td>' + '<a href="loadpost.html?id='+postsData[i].id+'" + rel="external" + " style="text-decoration:none ">'  + postsData[i].title.rendered + postsData[i].id+'</a>'+'</td>';
 ourHTMLString += '<td>' + '<a href="loadpost.html?id='+postsData[i].id+'"><img width="100%" src ="' + postsData[i]._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].source_url + '"  />' + '</a>'+'</td>';
 ourHTMLString += '<td>' + postsData[i].excerpt.rendered + '</td>';
 ourHTMLString+= '</tr>';
} 
portfolioPostsContainer.innerHTML = ourHTMLString;
}
```