# Refresh PHP variable inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

So I'm doing an operation inside the javascript to attribute a javascript variable to a php value that is obtained via txt file. But I want to repeatedly refresh. I've seen a few questions on this website like this one but didn't do the trick for me.

PHP code:

```
<?php
 $file = "nam.txt"; //Path to your *.txt file
 $contents = file($file);
 $nam = implode($contents);
?>
```

Javascript code (with setinterval but for now that is not working):

```
setInterval(function(){
 document.getElementById("nam").innerHTML = '<?php echo $nam; ?>';
}, 50);
```

Comment: Fyi, those are 50 miliseconds. Do you really want to update that fast?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), especially with that 50 mS interval. What is it you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I know, I just assimilated it randomly so you get what I want, is to use setInterval but for the PHP variables.

Comment: For now it just prints `$nam`, not reloading the `nam.txt`.

Comment: I know, that is what I want to do and Can't get it to work. I think it's possible with AJAX but no idea how to do it.

Comment: How should that work? PHP runs on the server, JS in the browser. Probably, you want to refresh the data using an AJAX request?

Comment: Google how to do it with ajax if you have no idea how to then come back with an issue you run into there.

Comment: @MiguelCasanova The easiest solution I can think of is indeed AJAX. If you have no idea how that works, it might be easier to follow a couple of online courses or tutorials since AJAX is pretty basic knowledge in web development. No offense, we all started like that!

Comment: I googled it and couldn't get it to work because it was way too much different from my problem and couldn't assimilate both. I want to refresh the data using AJAX, just don't know why.

Comment: @MiguelCasanova Feel free to comment down the problem you face in implementing the method i've mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 2):

**The Problem**

PHP is evaluated only when the request is made to the server, and once the server sends the response (*sending the data of the `.txt` file*), even if the contents of the file change, it cannot be retrieved (*unless another request is made to the server*)

**Solution**

In the `setInterval` function, make an `ajax` request to some page, and program that page to return the contents of the file. This way you can update the page in real-time as well as get the updated content after page load as well.

If you're new to AJAX, this might be helpful

[Ajax tutorial for post and get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get)