# Repeat PHP function every 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

So I have a code, where a number is retrieved from a text file and is displayed through HTML.

The thing is that it only retrieves the number when I refresh the page. If I change the number on other page, it doesn't change on the other page.

I've seen similar questions before, most of them said to use AJAX, but I don't understand much about AJAX and I only need it for this bit of code, it's not like I'm going to constantly use it. I would like to know if there is any other besides AJAX and if there is only AJAX, please present examples of code.

PHP code:

```
<?php
    $file = "num.txt"; //Path to your *.txt file
    $contents = file($file);
    $num = implode($contents);
?>
```

JavaScript code. Basically it gets the PHP value and outputs to the html.

```
document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = '<?php echo $num; ?>';
```

Keep in mind, I don't want to refresh the page. Just the variable.

---

**EDIT:** PHP code - Getting an error - Notice: Undefined index: keynum in C:\xampp\htdocs\num.php on line 3

Here is the code of the PHP

```
<?php
    $keynum = $_POST['keynum'];
    $post = "INSERT INTO post (keynum) VALUES ($keynum)";
    $fileLocation = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/num.txt";
    $file = fopen($fileLocation,"w");
    $content = $keynum;
    fwrite($file,$content);
    fclose($file);
    echo 'Response';
    die();
 ?>
```

Comment: Didn't you [already ask this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51061645/refresh-php-variable-inside-a-javascript-function)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh PHP variable inside a javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51061645/refresh-php-variable-inside-a-javascript-function)

Comment: Oddly, all your questions today are about this one problem.

Comment: Wait... what? What does that edit have to do with your original question? Where did that code come from, where was there a mention of a form submit? Or updating a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get_nbr.php

```
 <?php
 $file = "num.txt"; //Path to your *.txt file
 $contents = file($file);
 $num = implode($contents);
 echo $num;
 ?>
```

index.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!---trigger get_nbr() on page load on an infinite loop every two seconds -->
<body onload="setInterval(get_nbr, 2000)">
<script>
  function get_nbr() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "get_nbr.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
  }
 </script> 
<p id="num"></p>
```

Comment: Value not changing.

Comment: Keep in mind that the php code is in the same file as the javascript.

Comment: Well, my answer is working Perfectly based on the event of having all three files : get_nbr.php, index.php and num.txt .... Do you want to perform anything with the number you get ?

Comment: Got it working, but, when I dont change the value, it disappears, but it works fine if I constantly change it.

Comment: FINALLY WORKING. Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)

Comment: One thing now. I can only manage to get one working. I need 4 simultaneously. I tried separating them from function and in different scripts and it didn't work. All of them work but if it's just one at a time. If I add another function, it works alone but if there's two it doesn't work.

Comment: It's the onload that is screwing things up. How do I get multiple ones there?

Comment: you can get rid of that onload, and put  setInterval(get_nbr, 2000); in the end of the javascript code

Comment: Do you have 4 txt files and want to display/use them ?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want using [**XMLHttpRequest**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), like this:

```js
function updateData() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };      
  
  xhttp.open('GET', '/num.php', true);
  xhttp.send();
}

setInterval(updateData, 2000);
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: keynum in C:\xampp\htdocs\num.php on line 3
Response

Comment: I get that error. num.php is the php file that writes on the txt. Here is the code

Comment: <?php
$keynum = $_POST['keynum'];
$post = "INSERT INTO post (keynum) VALUES ($keynum)";
     $fileLocation = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/num.txt";
  $file = fopen($fileLocation,"w");
  $content = $keynum;
  fwrite($file,$content);
  fclose($file);
  echo 'Response';
die();
?>

Comment: Please, update your question with your PHP code you just posted above with any errors you get, so we can help you more easily. Thanks!

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you have any idea what the error might be? The value isn't changing either

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refresh the variable without refreshing the page, then you need to use an asynchronous request. It doesn't need to be AJAX, you can use the native `XMLHttpRequest()` function.

If you want more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Answer (score 1):

or with jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({url:"num.php", success:function(result){
            $("#num").html(result);
        }});
    }, 3000);
</script>

<textarea id="num"></textarea>
```

Comment: It gives this error on num.php Notice: Undefined index: keynum in C:\xampp\htdocs\num.php on line 3

Comment: @MiguelCasanova but I didn’t give you code of num.php :)

Comment: @MiguelCasanova because there is no POST variable with index keynum. What info you want to send to script?

Answer (score 0):

like this.

```
let url = ""; //whatever url your requesting.

setInterval(function(){
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET" , url , true);
    x.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200)
        {
             document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = x.responseText;
        }
    }
    x.send();
} , 2000);
```

-- UPDATE , added post --

```
setInterval(function(){
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open("POST" , url , true);
        x.setRequestHeader("Content-Type" , "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        x.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200)
            {
                 document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = x.responseText;
            }
        }
        x.send("postVar1=123");
    } , 2000);
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: keynum in C:\xampp\htdocs\num.php on line 3 Response. I get that error. num.php is the php file that writes on the txt. Here is the code

Comment: <?php $keynum = $_POST['keynum']; $post = "INSERT INTO post (keynum) VALUES ($keynum)"; $fileLocation = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/num.txt"; $file = fopen($fileLocation,"w"); $content = $keynum; fwrite($file,$content); fclose($file); echo 'Response'; die(); ?>

Comment: postVar1 = $_POST['postVar1'] in php , just swap out the values

Comment: Didn't seem to work. Didn't give the error, but the value didn't change.

Comment: var_dump your post variable