# How to GET javascript data in PHP file without page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am building my best attempt at a twitter clone and have run into a bit of a problem.  I want to be able to click on a post and, without a page refresh, display that post in the overlay of the page (as you would on a twitter feed to look at replies, etc.).

In script.js, I check for a click and try to change the url.

```
$('body').on("click", ".chirp", function(){
 var uid = $_GET['id'];
 var pid = $(this).attr("id");
 var pidSplit = pid.split("chirp");
 var messageID = pidSplit[1];
 var obj = {foo: "status"};
 $('.chirpOverlay').addClass("active");
 window.history.pushState(obj, "Status", "profile.php?id="+uid+"&status="+pid);
});
```

The javascript works as intended...but as I will soon find out, the victory is short-lived.


In profile.php, I attempt to GET the status id from the URL parameter.

```
<?php
$status_id = $_GET['status'];
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM chirps WHERE id='$status_id'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
  $c = $sql->fetch_object();
}
?>
```

This doesn't work because, as I've learned, using 'window.history.pushState' only changes the url- but doesn't load the page.  Thus the $_GET statement fails.  I need a way to get the id of the post I click on into profile.php without a page refresh.  Even if it means taking a different approach (instead of using a URL parameter).

PS: I tried to do an XMLHttpRequest as well- to no avail. :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer is only one word : `ajax`

Comment: as @Ashraf say you can use ajax [see example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get)

Comment: @Ashraf from seeing other people's projects it seems that ajax would be the option, but the syntax confuses me and I'm not sure how to apply it in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a AJAX-based solution to my problem.

I created a new php file called "chirp_open_ref.php" and added this ajax to script.js:

```
var datastring = 'status=' + messageID;
$.ajax({
    url: "chirp_open_ref.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: datastring,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data){
        $('.chirp-container').html(data);
    }
});
```

Inside of 'chirp_open_ref.php':

```
<?php
require 'core.inc.php';

if (isset($_POST['status']) && isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
  $chirp_id = $_POST['status'];
  $c = "";
  $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM chirps WHERE id='$chirp_id'");
  if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
    $c = $sql->fetch_object();
  }
  include'chirp.inc.php';
}
?>
```

'chirp.inc.php' is simply a template for the layout/structure of each post.
This works like a charm, but I am always open to any criticism of how I am performing this.  Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: Just a reminder that your SQL queries are very vulnerable to SQL injections.  Take an hour to learn how to parameterize your queries.  You also need to find out a way to validate your variables server side.  There is nothing stopping someone from just sending a malformed url to `chirp_open_ref.php`.   Other than that looks like your on the right path.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.  I will definitely look that!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on("click", ".chirp", function(){
    var uid = $_GET['id'];
    var pid = $(this).attr("id");
    var pidSplit = pid.split("chirp");
    var messageID = pidSplit[1];
    var obj = {foo: "status"};

    $('.chirpOverlay').addClass("active");

    $.ajax({
        url: "profile.php?id="+uid+"&status="+pid,
        type: "GET",
        data: obj,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: The console logs my ENTIRE profile.php page (html structure and all).  Not working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You need to just get something up and going that works and then you can add more to it as you figure things out.  This should give you a good starting place.

Here are your two files.  Make sure they are both in the same directory.

You will need to make sure you have a jquery version loaded.  Put this on whatever page you are calling the script.js from.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('body').click(function(){

    var id; //define your id.
    var pid;  //define your pid.

    var datastring = 'id=' + uid + '&status=' + pid;
    console.log(datastring);
      $.ajax({

        url: 'profile.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: datastring,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
          console.log('Made it to the success function: ' + data);
          if (data) {
            //It works, do something.
            console.log(data);

          } else{
            //It does not work, do something.
            console.log('Your ajax failed to get the info from your php page. Keep troubleshooting');

            }

        }

      });    

  });

});
```

profile.php

```
<?php

/*
$status_id = $_POST['status'];  //This needs to be sanitized and validated.
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM chirps WHERE id='$status_id'"); //This is unsafe sql practice.
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
$c = $sql->fetch_object();
}
echo json_encode($c); //This is what gets sent back to script.js
*/

echo 'You made it to your php page.';

?>
```

A few things:

- You can not call any php variable from within your js.  `var uid = $_GET['id'];` does not work.
- Any value that you pass to the php page needs to be validated to make sure it is a legitimate value.
- Your SQL query is prone to sql injections.  Please read up on how to parameterize your queries. [Good Mysqli Practices](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I tried what you said but NOTHING was logged to the console.  Also, the JS $_GET was a special variable somebody showed how to create online to mimic the PHP version.

Comment: Maybe take the # out of the `$('#body')`.  And did you receive any errors.

Comment: In my code I added `console.log(datastring);`  What does that show you.

Comment: I know for a fact the JQuery selector is working fine.  'id=1&status=9' is the datastring logged

Comment: added the console.log in the success function see what that says.

Comment: console.log(datastring) gives me: 'id=1&status=9'.  The one in the success function prints nothing.

Comment: Did it say "Made it to the success function: "?

Comment: Nope.  Nothing at all.

Comment: I made a change to the profile.php page.  Make the changes and run again.  See what your console says.

Comment: No change from before.

Comment: That makes me think that the url to profile.php is not correct.

Comment: Last night had to shut off computer for severe weather.  Sat down on my bed when it hit me... I never went up a directory ("../profile.php") in script.js to get out of my scripts folder.  HOWEVER, after doing this I am still not getting anything logged to the console from the success function.

Comment: I would use the full url path to profile.php for testing purposes.  I can't really see any reason this code is not working.  It's something stupid at this point.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.  If you look at the answer I just posted, I've found a solution :)

Comment: Good, Im glad you got it working.  Hope the rest of your project goes well.