# Javascript - saving seats to db

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, function, symfony

I am working with https://github.com/mateuszmarkowski/jQuery-Seat-Charts in my Symofny project.. I defined my seat numbers..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var firstSeatLabel = 1;

var rowRange = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');

var sc = $('#seat-map').seatCharts({
        map: [
            'eeeee_eeeee',
            'eeeee_eeeee',
            'eeeee_eeeee',
            'eeeee_eeeee',
            'eeeee_eeeee',
            'eeeee_eeeee',
            'eeeee_eeeee',
            'eeeee_eeeee',
            'eeeee_eeeee',
        ],
    naming : {
        top : false,
        getLabel : function (character, row, column) {
            return rowRange[row - 1].toUpperCase() + column;
        },
    }
 });

});
```

It looks like this

[image]

Now I need to add to my database row each field individually. I worked with my Symfony logic but it's JavaScript that I can not handle. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to post this to Syfmony controller? Then why don't you use `jQuery Ajax` ? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I am currently trying to figure it out. I am trying to post it trought Controller..

Comment: Take a look at how `Ajax` post and get works. You will find lots of tutorials if you search. I found this. Might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get