# Populate Form Fields based on Dynamic Dropdown selection using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

**I am new to PHP.**

I'd relly appreciate it if someone could please point me in the right direction for a tutorial on how to populate multiple text fields based on a dynamic drop-down list selection (entries from a MySQL table).
I'm new to PHP and MySQL and I'm busy trying to build a page that when I select an item from a drop-down list, that has been populated from a MySQL table, it populates multiple text fields with the appropriate information from that table

For example, if I select "client name" from the selection box then the text fields Email, Phone and Address get populated with "Client name", email, phone, address from the same table.
columns are = id, name, email, phone, address, key person, additional info

**MY PHP CODE FOR SELECTBOX:**

```
    <?php
    include('../db_connection.php');
    $sql="SELECT name,id FROM add_client order by name"; 
    echo "<select name=name value=''>Client Name</option>"; // list box select command
    foreach ($con->query($sql) as $row){//Array or records stored in $row
    echo "<option value=$row[id]>$row[name]</option>"; 
    }
    echo "</select>";// Closing of list box
    ?>
```

[Screenshot# 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KBC1.png)

[table- column (for Reference)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA5Gw.png)

[Screenshot# 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6zbX.png)

My Table name is: add_client
Db Connection file: db_connection.php

Comment: You want to get the data without refresh the page?

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax (php, mysql, jquery) on click event of fetch button, and populate data in input fields.

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get)