# Save user's input instantly to mySql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm aware about passing user input to another php page, get it by $_POST or GET and run a query, but I see in some pages that when I give them an input it's saved immediately, without going to another link. I don't know whether they are using mySQL database, but I want to know how to make that possible in the case of mySQL. Is the data saved in a JSON file or something and passed to the server when the page is closed?

Comment: there's no way for us to know about the specific site's you're referring to since it could be done many ways.  chances are pretty high they used ajax.

Comment: Look into AJAX e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get

Comment: use ajax call and on success you can redirect wherever you want to redirect

Comment: yeah maybe also consider ajax.  or even ajax.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use Ajax or write php code on the same page.
For example :

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" placeholder="Input1" name="firstInput">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$input=$_POST['firstInput'];

 //Here you can run your query make sure to make database connection first
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"query goes here"); 
}

?>
```