# Concatenate 2 form fields with button

Tags: php, string, forms, post, get

I am trying to concatenate the values of 2 fields when the user presses the button. After pressing the button it should display the concatenated string. Can't seem to figure this out as this is my first time playing with html forms. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="GET">
<input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="Number 1">
<input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Number 2">
<br>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Generate</button>
</form>
<p>Response:</p>
<?php
if (isset($_GET["submit"])) {
$name = $_GET['num1'] . ' ' . $_GET['num2'];
echo $name;
}
?>



</body>


</html>
```

It seems like the info is getting passed to the URL when I click the button because this is what it shows when entering "aaaa" and "bbbb":

```
    file:///storage/emulated/0/web-files/index.php?num1=aaaa&num2=bbbb&submit=submit
```

Comment: Does changing `valie` (a typo) to `value` on the button fix your form?

Comment: @potNPan Thanks but I still am not getting anything.

Comment: I don't think it will display anything because you're embedding php code inside html. And since you're not using Ajax, your <p> content won't change as php produces static content when executed as a part of html.

Comment: Also if you're just trying to concatenate the two numbers, why not just use javascript.

Comment: @Dr.KevinWang Thanks for your input. I'm new to this and learning. Can you please show me how it would work using ajax? Thanks

Comment: @Dr.KevinWang They're not necessarily two numbers, as they are text fields.

Comment: @harvey You can check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

use

> isset($_GET['submit'])

instead of

> isset($_GET["submit"])

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the url provided, you are directly opening a php file from a browser. Try to install apache server and then keep the file in root directory. It will definitely work. 
If you want to continue with php, you can go through this link https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu
Or if you just want to concatenate those input values you can use JavaScript to do the job and a simple html file will help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function concatme()
            {
                var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
                var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
                document.getElementById("response").innerText = num1 + ' ' +num2;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="num1" id="num1" placeholder="Number 1">
        <input type="text" name="num2" id="num2" placeholder="Number 2">
    </form>
    <br>
    <button  value="submit" onclick="concatme()">Generate</button>
    <p id="response"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct input "submit" in your form, so retry with :

```html
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Instead this button, and a button have to be write like this :

```html
<input type="button" name="btnName" value="btnValue"/>
```

It seem it can work on some browser with `<button>` but it's not the standard way.

Edit: your url is strange too, are you sure php is right running.

Comment: I think it will not works thought... what is the form url? do you fall on this form page when you submit?
Try adding the action `<form method="GET" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">`. Your file:// is strange, it must be http://