# How to use AJAX for dependent drop down lists?

Tags: ajax, django-models, html-select

I want my "Location" drop down list to be dependent on my "Client" drop down list. My models:

```
class Client(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Location(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

What is the next step after this?

Should I put a FK somewhere?

What is the AJAX code for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display two dropdowns, first one with `Client` options and second one with `Location` options, with `Locations` changing on `Client` dropdown change you should add a js event handler, for example with jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '#clients', () => { 
    ...call locations endpoint and update locations options... 
})
```

On backend append your `Location` model with a `Client` FK and make an endpoint for path `app/locations/<int:client_id>/` where you select `Locations` based on a `Client`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
...
def locations(request, client_id):
    client = get_object_or_404(Client, id=client_id)
    locations = Location.objects.filter(client=client)
    return JsonResponse(dict(locations=locations), status=200)
```

Comment: Where would i code "def locations..."? Is it under models.py or views.py? Also how do i call the  endpoints in the jQuery?

Comment: `def locations` is a view, so it should be inside `app/views.py`. I made an example with function-based view, you can use class-based if you like it more.


To make an ajax call in jQuery look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get).