# How to export axios requests on node js from my routes files to the main app.js?

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I have a folder for my routes, so I want to export the routes to my `app.js` using axios.

I just don't know how to add this axios routes to my `app.js` file as I do with normal routers from `express.Router()`

This is my `USER.JS` file inside `routes` folder on my porject:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const userController = require('../controllers/userController')
const axios = require('axios')

router.get('/user', userController.getUserLogin)
router.get('/userRegister', userController.getUserRegister)
router.post('/user', userController.postUserLogin)
router.post('/userRegister', userController.postUserRegister)

module.exports = axios.get('/user', userController.getUserLogin)

module.exports = router
```

This is my `app.js`:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user')

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use('/', userRoutes)

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
    console.log(`application running`)
})
```

Comment: you realize axios does not create a route?

Answer (score 0):

> how to add this axios routes

Simple answer: There's **no** `axios routes`

From `npm` axios describes itself as:

> Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js

Notice the word `client`. It's a `client` not `server`. Its function is to make http calls to some resource served by server.

From `npm`, the top 2 listed features

> Make XMLHttpRequests from the browser
>
> Make http requests from node.js

To make `express` routes you either use instance of default `express` class or `express.Router()` class.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();

// route
app.get('/myroute', (req, res) => {})

// using Router
const router = express.Router()
router.get('/myroute', (req, res) => {})
```

Comment: Ok thank you, so how would I send a POST or GET request from my HTML form to my routes folder using Axios without refreshing the page?

Comment: here is a simple `AJAX` example. replace AJAX with axios

Comment: Opps, forgot to paste the link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get