# Website: Send data from javascript (client) to python (server)

Tags: javascript, python, simplehttpserver

I have wrote a website using html/css and javascript and I am running this site using a simple python script

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8000
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

the website is running just fine. However I am trying to understand how can I send data from the js client to the python server? Let's settle a simple example. Let's assume that I have a simple html text input and a simple html button and I am writing some text to the field, how am I supposed to send this text, when I am pressing the button, to the server?

NOTE: I am using pure javascript so far

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax tutorial for post and get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get)

Comment: have you checked the fetch api or axios

Comment: @YegorZaremba I am trying to used pure javascript as you can read on the NOTE section. I am asking for the python script as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement in Python a handler that can handle a POST or a PUT request onto a given URL. And in javascript, you just send your HTTP request on this URL with the correct HTTP method and with data in the body of your request.

Comment: You should have a look at a simple Python library for building your Web server. For example Flask: https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask/

Comment: I was not aware of flask I made a search online about it and I found the example I was asking for [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_http_methods.htm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_http_methods.htm)

Comment: Glad to be helpful. :-)