# Get textarea edited text on script by JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, textarea

I need to get the text a user enters in a textarea, in a script from JSP. I tried this code but get null value:

```
<label for="userText"></label>
<textarea name="userText" id="userText">text edited by the user</textarea>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Ok</button>

function myFunction() {
    <%System.out.print(request.getParameter("userText"));%>
}
```

I can i get it?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Java Script for this

```
var message = $('textarea#userText').val();
```

Comment: I need to use a user text on JSP server side

Comment: You will have to get this value and make a ajax call to send it to the server side

Comment: I tried this code but do nothing:  `<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendMail() {
        $('input').on('click', function () {
            var message = $('textarea#userText').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/servlet',
                data: {"messageLessor": message}
            });
        });
    }
</script>` I don't know Ajax well

Comment: put an javascript alert and check if you are getting the message, the use this link to make the ajax request https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get and put a debug point on your servlet class to see if you are able to get the message there.