# I try passing js variable but php does not recognize the value of an span element

Tags: javascript, php, html

I tried getting span tag element but when i using it to mysql query Im not getting the result that i want, But if i set manually the specific date in php $varibale i get the data the only problem is the   ';
?>
and when i tried to use $sample in this
$query = " SELECT * FROM `tblblotter` WHERE reportDate LIKE '%".$sample."%'   ";
it does not work
but if i try
$query = " SELECT * FROM `tblblotter` WHERE reportDate LIKE '%".'04/07/2022'."%'   ";
it will show the result
[All I wanted to do is to get specific date chartjs using bar and display the data in table when the user click the specific bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fahjs.png)

```html
<?php
$username="root";
$password= "";
$database="micra";
try {
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;database=$database,",$username,$password);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die("ERROR:Could not connect".$e->getMessage());
}
?>
 
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
      .chartMenu {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 40px;
        background: #1A1A1A;
        color: rgba(255, 26, 104, 1);
      }
      .chartMenu p {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
      }
      .chartCard {
        width: 100vw;
        height: calc(100vh - 40px);
        background: rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .chartBox {
        width: 700px; 
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border: solid 3px rgba(255, 26, 104, 1);
        background: white;
      }
         
      #barModal.hide{
        z-index:-1;
        opacity: 0;
         transition:opacity 0.2s;

      }
        #barModal{
        z-index:1;
        opacity: 100;
        transition:opacity 0.2s;
         align-items: center;
           text-align: center;
      }
      .modal-background{
        position: fixed;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
      }
      .modal{

        margin-top:10%;
        margin-left:30%; 
        width: 700px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: white;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow:column;

      }
      .modal-header,.modal-body,.modal-footer{
        border:1px solid#666;
        border-top:1px;
        border-left:1px;
        border-right:1px;
        padding: 20px;  
      }
      .modal-body{
        flex:1 1 auto;
      }
      .btn{
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
        border: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: white;
      }
      .btn.danger{
        background-color: rgba(255,26,104,1);
        border: 1px solid rgba(255,26,104,1);

      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="chartMenu">
    </div>
    <div class="chartCard">
      <div class="chartBox">
    <LABEL>START DATE:</LABEL> <input type="date" onchange="stratDateFilter(this)" id="startDate" value="" min="2022-01-01">
    <LABEL>END DATE:</LABEL> <input type="date" onchange="endDateFilter(this)" id="endDate" value="" min="2022-04-02">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
          
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
    try {
      $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*), reportDate FROM micra.tblblotter GROUP BY reportDate";
      $result = $pdo ->query($sql);
      if ($result ->rowCount()>0) {
        while ($row = $result ->fetch()) {
          $dateArray[] = $row["reportDate"];
          $orderPrice[] = $row["COUNT(*)"];
         
   
        }

        unset($result);
  
      }else{
        echo "No result in Db";
      }
             
    } catch(PDOExeption $e){
      die("Error");
      unset($pdo);

    }

    ?>
    <div class="container">
    <div id="barModal" class="modal-background">
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-header">
       <h3><b>Selected Date: <span  class="label"></span></b></h3>
       <h3><b><span id="DateSelected"></span></b></h3>   
        <?php
            $sample = '<span id="DateSelected"></span>';
        ?>
      </div>
      <h3><b>Total number of reports that day: <span id="DateSelected"  class="value"></span></b></h3>
  <div class="modal-body">
   <div class="table table-responsive">
<?php 
echo $sample;
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$database = "micra"; 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database); 
$query = " SELECT * FROM `tblblotter` WHERE reportDate LIKE '%".<script>."%'   ";
     
echo '<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2"> 
      <tr> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">Date reported</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">Time reported</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">Location of incident</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">Complainant first name</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">Complainant last name</font> </td> 
      </tr>';

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $field1name = $row["reportDate"];
        $field2name = $row["reportTime"];
        $field3name = $row["locationofincident"];
        $field4name = $row["complainantfirstname"];
        $field5name = $row["complainantlastname"]; 
        echo '<tr> 
                  <td>'.$field1name.'</td> 
                  <td>'.$field2name.'</td> 
                  <td>'.$field3name.'</td> 
                  <td>'.$field4name.'</td> 
                  <td>'.$field5name.'</td> 
              </tr>';
    }
    $result->free();
} 
?>
    </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button onclick="modalClose()" class="btn danger">Close</button>
        <button  class="btn danger">Print</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      const dateArrayJS= <?php echo json_encode($dateArray); ?>;
      const dateChartJS = dateArrayJS.map((day,index)=>{
        let dayjs = new Date(day);
        return dayjs.setHours(0,0,0,0);

      });  

    // setup 
    const data = {
      labels: dateChartJS,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Total Number of report',
        data: <?php echo json_encode($orderPrice); ?>,

        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
          
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    };

    // config 
    const config = {
      type: 'bar',
      data,

      options: {
        scales: {
          x:{
            min:'2022-04-01',
            max:'2022-04-30',
            type:'time',

            time:{
              unit:'day'
            }
          },
          y: {
        title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Number of Submitted Report'
            },
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      }

    };
    const ctx =document.getElementById('myChart');
    const myChart = new Chart(
      ctx,
      config
    );
    const barModal = document.getElementById('barModal');
    function modalClose(){
      barModal.classList.toggle('hide');
    }
    
    function clickHandler(click){

    const points = myChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(click,'nearest',{
      intersect:true},true);

   if(points[0]){
    const firstPoint = points[0];
    var timestamps = myChart.data.labels[firstPoint.index];
    var dates2 = new Date(timestamps);
    var dd = String(dates2.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(dates2.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
    var yyyy = dates2.getFullYear();

    var newDate  = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

    var newdate= (dates2.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + dates2.getDate() + '/' +  dates2.getFullYear();
    var values =  myChart.data.datasets[firstPoint.datasetIndex].data[firstPoint.index];
    console.log(document.getElementById("DateSelected").innerHTML = newDate);
    console.log(points[0]);
    var datadisplay = document.querySelectorAll('.label');
    datadisplay.forEach(label =>{
      label.innerText = newDate;
      
    }) 
    var datavaluedisplay = document.querySelectorAll('.value');
    datavaluedisplay.forEach(value =>{
      value.innerText =values;
    })
    barModal.classList.toggle('hide');
   }
   myChart.update();
    }
   ctx.onclick =clickHandler;

      function stratDateFilter(date){
      const startDate = new Date(date.value);
       var minToDate = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
      document.getElementById("endDate").setAttribute("min", minToDate);
      myChart.config.options.scales.x.min = startDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
      myChart.update();
      }

      function endDateFilter(date){
      const endDate = new Date(date.value);
      myChart.config.options.scales.x.max = endDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
      myChart.update();
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$query = " SELECT * FROM tblblotter WHERE reportDate LIKE '%".<script>."%'` this is wrong what you did at the end `<script>`, you can use ajax call function to pass the date to php then get the output. [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get)

Comment: $query = " SELECT * FROM tblblotter WHERE reportDate LIKE '%".<script>."%' is intended  i just really need to pass the variable from js to php
I really use this code
$query = " SELECT * FROM tblblotter WHERE reportDate LIKE '%".$sample."%'
but it does not work

Comment: Do it with `AJAX` [Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get), You cannot pass variable values from the current page JavaScript code to the current page PHP code.